# Login Screen using httpurlconnection android

Tags: java, android

Is there any possible way to make login screen using httpurlconnection class.  if yes how? i have problem passing nvps. Reply soon.

Comment: Maybe you want to share some code?

Comment: In order to get good responses, here are a few things to keep in mind. 1) Assume you'll need to write all the code yourself. We'll generally only point you in the right direction. 2) What Have You Tried? (Google that phrase). We need to see your attempts at solving this. 3) Make sure you've thoroughly checked documentation and a search engine. If someone else finds the answer that way, you'll get a curt "RTD" or "LMGTFY" and a LOT of downvotes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes it is possible and there are a few examples,check them out:

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-automate-login-a-website-java-example/

[Android: How to programatically login to website and retrieve data from it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22717806/android-how-to-programatically-login-to-website-and-retrieve-data-from-it)