# Extract html data after logging into website from android app

Tags: android, html, web

I recently started to learn to develop apps for android, but I'm stuck for quite a while on 1 problem:
I want to log from my app to a website (http://student.tu-sofia.bg/) and download some data from it, so I can use it later in my app. I have red different articles and tried different things but in the end nothing worked. The closest thing that I got as a result was receiving the source code of the login page( tried this [Android: How to programatically login to website and retrieve data from it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22717806/android-how-to-programatically-login-to-website-and-retrieve-data-from-it#))
Can someone tell my what I am doing wrong or give an advice how I should approach this ?

Comment: do you want to keep sessions in server ?

Comment: no, after you log into the website there is a html table with the student's grades. I just want to take that data and afterwards I don't need the connection

Comment: Develop an API for login and retrieve data as json.